# C macro expansion explanation

Tags: c, macros

I have inherited a lot of code and I am stumbling on this expansion.  I understand what it does, I don't understand how it does it.

```
#define OFFSETOF(structure, item)     ((u16)&(((structure*)0)->item))
```

To be more specific, I get most of it except this part `((structure*)0)`.  I don't get what the zero is doing or what it is there for.

If you need to know, 'structure' is just a `typedef struct{}` and item is a member in the

```
 struct{
    u32 my_example_item;
}
```

Again, the zero is confusing the heck out of me.

Comment: One explanation for the macro is that the author doesn't know that the standard C language provides an `offsetof` macro in the standard header `<stddef.h>`.

Comment: The question actually isn't a duplicate of that one, because it is specifically asking about the null pointer constant. I prepared an answer to the question what the zero is doing there, but was not able to save. Please ask a more specific question, just about that expression, without the "red herring" material about the OFFSETOF macro.

Answer (score 2):

- `structure` is a type
- `(structure*)` is a pointer
- `(structure*)0` is a null pointer of type `structure*`
- `->item` gets the `item` member of the object pointed at
- `(((structure*)0)->item)` pretends there's a `structure` at position 0 in memory, and refers to it's item.
- `&(((structure*)0)->item)` gets the address of that item, which will be equal to the offset of `item` in the object.  The type of this address is `u32*` (since `item` is a `u32`)
- `((u16)&(((structure*)0)->item))` converts that address to a `u16`, so it's a proper offset type.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to a common implementation of the `offsetof()` macro, defined in the C standard header `<stddef.h>`. The code actually has undefined behavior, but it's likely to work for most C implementations.

It yields the offset, in bytes, of `item` from the beginning of type `structure`. `structure` should be a struct type (it could be a union, but then `OFFSETOF` will always yield 0), and `item` is a member of that structure (or union) type.

`(structure*)0` is a null pointer of type *pointer to `structure`*.

`((structure*)0)->item` refers to the `item` member of the nonexistent `structure` object at the address that a null pointer points to. Yes, that's odd. *If* a null pointer is represented as memory address 0, and `item` is at an offset of, say, 12 bytes, then the object referred to by `((structure*)0)->item` is at memory address 12. This makes a lot of assumptions about the memory model of the current system. Those assumptions are commonly valid; if they're not, this thing will probably blow up in your face.

`&(((structure*)0)->item)` is the address of that mythical object at address 12.

Finally, `((u16)&(((structure*)0)->item))` is memory address 12 (of type `structure*`) explicitly converted to `u16`. Presumably `u16` is an unsigned 16-bit integer type (if so, it would make more sense to use the standard `uint16_t`).

So given a structure type `structure`, and a member `item` at offset 12, this macro would expand to an expression that yields the value 12.

Keep in mind that addresses (pointer values) *are not* numbers; they're conceptually distinct concepts. This macro will work only for systems that use a particularly memory model, one that isn't specified by the C standard.

I'm not sure why the result is of type `u16`. The standard `offsetof` macro yields a value of type `size_t`.

For systems that use a different memory model (for example, if a null pointer is represented as all-bits-one or `0xdeadbeef`), this `OFFSETOF` macro would not work, and the standard `offsetof` macro would have to tailored to work on that particular system. That's part of the reason `offsetof` is in the standard library, so it can be implemented in a way that works on each system.